# Eclipse - Command line URL argument cutting off https

Tags: java, eclipse

EDIT: Code for InstallCerts is here:
http://code.google.com/p/java-use-examples/source/browse/trunk/src/com/aw/ad/util/InstallCert.java

I am trying to run a java program in eclipse that takes a URL (eg `https://myurl.com`) as an argument. When I go to Run Configurations -> Arguments and paste in the URL, it looks fine. I click Apply.

The problem starts when I click Run. For some reason, eclipse removes the `https:` at the start of the URL and I get an error saying:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "//myurl.com"
```

Notice the lack of `https:`?

Anyway, if someone can point me in the right direction to resolve this, I'd be very grateful.

I should also point out, I tried to create a Variable as well, to hold the URL, but I got the same error. Likewise when I quoted the URL.

Thanks.

Comment: quoting unquoting should not have any effect in this case. Can you paste _exact_ command here? Also, NumberFormatException points to some other issue.

Comment: Nishant, I'm just clicking the green "Run" button in eclipse, so theres no exact command. I am putting the URL in the Arguments section of the project (Run Configuratrions -> Arguments tab).

Comment: Have you tried running your code from the command line with that argument, what happens then?

Comment: ignoring the lack of https...why are you trying to convert that arg to a number. Therein may lie your problem.

Comment: It looks to me that you are trying to convert that parameter into a number... Are you sure you are not parsing the port number and the host in different parameter to what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a "NumberFormatException" which means  you are trying to convert a String to int in your code . I think thats the real problem.

Comment: While it had nothing to do with the parameters I was passing in, there was somewhere in the code (line 58) that I managed to just comment out, as it seemed a bit weird. Now it gets passed that point, albeit with an `unknown host` error on line 94! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Quote it.

> "https://myurl.com"

**EDIT** : I just tried quote/unquote - it works either way. Can you post your code?

Cheers,Eugene

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that class searches for port. Do not use https://, instead refer to secure port e.g. my.site.com:443!